# How to get popular keywords in an array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array with all keywords of my site like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => keyword1
    [1] => keyword1
    [2] => keyword1
    [3] => keyword1
    [4] => keyword1
    [5] => keyword1
    [6] => keyword1
    [7] => keyword1
    [8] => keyword1
    [9] => keyword1
    [10] => keyword2
    [11] => keyword2
    [12] => keyword2
    [13] => keyword3
    [14] => keyword3
    [15] => keyword3
    [16] => keyword3
    [17] => keyword3
    [18] => keyword3
    [19] => keyword4
    [20] => keyword4
    [21] => keyword4
    [22] => keyword4
    [23] => keyword4
    [24] => keyword5
)
```

And I want to find popular keywords, creating an array like this one:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => keyword1
            [count] => 10
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => keyword2
            [count] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => keyword3
            [count] => 6
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => keyword4
            [count] => 5
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => keyword5
            [count] => 1
        )

)
```

Also I want to sort by count of keywords and remove duplicated values and set every keyword in a sub array.

Comment: [array_count_values()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

Comment: For the sake of your next issues on PHP, try to type your intent on Google followed by the word "php" and I swear you won't be regret, there's plenty of material starting with it's official documentation that covers every single bundled function for array purposes. If you can't find your answers at all, then you can consider asking here at SO since a research effort has been made before it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array_count_values` will output the count as like

```
Array
(
    [keyword1] => 10
    [keyword2] => 3
    [keyword3] => 6
    [keyword4] => 5
    [keyword5] => 1
)
```

But For your desired output you need to use `foreach`

[**Demo**](https://ideone.com/9f5bon)

```
$arra = Array
(
    0 => "keyword1",
    1 => "keyword1",
    2 => "keyword1",
    3 => "keyword1",
    4 => "keyword1",
    5 => "keyword1",
    6 => "keyword1",
    7 => "keyword1",
    8 => "keyword1",
    9 => "keyword1",
    10 => "keyword2",
    11 => "keyword2",
    12 => "keyword2",
    13 => "keyword3",
    14 => "keyword3",
    15 => "keyword3",
    16 => "keyword3",
    17 => "keyword3",
    18 => "keyword3",
    19 => "keyword4",
    20 => "keyword4",
    21 => "keyword4",
    22 => "keyword4",
    23 => "keyword4",
    24 => "keyword5"
);

$newarray = array_count_values($arra);
$output = array();
foreach($newarray as $key=>$val) {
    $output[] = array("0"=>$key, "count"=>$val);
}

echo '<pre>';print_r($output);echo '</pre>';
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => keyword1
            [count] => 10
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => keyword2
            [count] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => keyword3
            [count] => 6
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => keyword4
            [count] => 5
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => keyword5
            [count] => 1
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `array_count_values()` !

Answer (score 0):

```
$test=your array; //store your array in a variable
$val = array_count_values($test); //count your array values
print_r($val);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this  function

```
  <?php
$items = Array(
             'keyword5','keyword5','keyword5','keyword5','keyword1','keyword1','keyword1','keyword2'
        );

$occurences = array_count_values($items);
print_r($occurences);

?>
```

and it will print your count of similar values.